# How does extends in TypeScript work?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following TypeScript code:

```
class BaseClassWithConstructor {
    private _id: number;
    constructor(id: number) {
        this._id = id;
    }
}

class DerivedClassWithConstructor extends BaseClassWithConstructor {
    private _name: string;
    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        this._name = name;
        super(id);
    }
}
```

Generates the following JavaScript code:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var BaseClassWithConstructor = (function () {
    function BaseClassWithConstructor(id) {
        this._id = id;
    }
    return BaseClassWithConstructor;
})();
var DerivedClassWithConstructor = (function (_super) {
    __extends(DerivedClassWithConstructor, _super);
    function DerivedClassWithConstructor(id, name) {
        this._name = name;
        _super.call(this, id);
    }
    return DerivedClassWithConstructor;
})(BaseClassWithConstructor);
```

`extends` seems to be implemented by the `__extends` function.

Being trying to work out the magic behind this function. I don't understand why
we have to copy properties in the base class to the derived class (i.e. `for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];`), and create a new object using the `__` function and hook up the prototypes between the `b`, `__`, `d` and an instance of `__`.

What is the reasoning behind all this?

Comment: Maybe to support future classing?

Answer (score 0):

Until ECMAScript support for classes goes native, the extends function polyfills the expected behaviour of inheritance.

If you are used to the normal JavaScript prototypical inheritance, you'll be wondering why it isn't just doing the `__.prototype = b.prototype;` part. If so, you'll be interested to know that the addition of `for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];` means that static members will be copied too. For example...

```
class BaseClassWithConstructor {
    private _id: number;
    constructor(id: number) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    static doIt() {
        alert('Done it');
    }
}

class DerivedClassWithConstructor extends BaseClassWithConstructor {
    private _name: string;
    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        this._name = name;
        super(id);
    }
}

DerivedClassWithConstructor.doIt();
```

Answer (score 0):

The generated javascript code can be divided in two parts:

`for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];`

is for "inheriting" the static properties of base class. Actually in the newest version of type script, this line of code has been substituted with

`extendStatics(d, b);`

where the definition of `extendStatics` is:

`var extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
        ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
        function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };`

The only difference is that in new version, manipulation of `[[prototype]]` is used if related behavior is supported by browsers, otherwise fallback to the old practice, i.e. copying every owned property from base class to derived class.

---

And as for

`function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();`

It is really a slightly fancier way of setting the `prototype` of `d` to a new instance of `b`. But instead of directly assigning `new b(...)` to `d.instance`, a dummy constructor `__` is used since for the purpose of setting prototype, we don't need the constructor `b` to be really invoked, and by using dummy function, we don't need to pass arguments to the constructor. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7533593/4794308) SO answer.